# How to get the percentage of execution of a lua script?

Tags: c, lua

I run Lua scripts inside c application in a separate task, I added a feature to check on the status of the running script if it's still running or completed.

I want to add some info in case of running script, I want to add the percentage executed from the running script, does Lua support this info by any mean.

I tried to use the info reported in Lua_debug, but it doesn't look to be correct (Like currentlin, definedline), I need the percentage over the whole script not just for a specific function.

Comment: As soon as your script contains ifs or loops you will have a very very hard time getting a meaningful percentage...

Comment: I have no problem with that, I don't need to calculate it based on the execution time or instructions, I just need something rough (number of lines)

Comment: Are you asking how to figure out how long it would take the script to run before actually running it? That sounds a bit like the halting problem to me. How would you know that running a given script will ever complete at all?

Comment: so if your script is 100 lines you want to know at regular intervals at what line it is currently? assuming you don't have loops just a sequence of tasks? Not clear what you are trying to do, perhaps provide an example of file and expected output.

Comment: Technically, the "whole script" _is_ a specific function. It has arguments and any number of return statements.

Comment: I just need to check the running script for example and know in which line is it executing, and check the total number of lines, and based on that i will have a simple way to know the percentage of the executed lines, so if the script is executing line # 30 and the total number of lines are 100 then I can say roughly that the execution is 30% coplete

Comment: updated my answer with some smarter code. now the code that you're running is separated from the runner code

Answer (score 1):

You could set a [debug hook](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.2.html) and listen to the hook events:

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/oM43K4)

```
local script = [[
    print 'hello'
    print 'world'
    for i=0,3 do
        local answer = 42
    end
]]

local script_function = loadstring(script)

local function count_lines ()
    local count = 0
    for k,v in script:gmatch '\n' do count = count+1 end
    return count
end

local function trace(total_lines)
    local max_last_line = 0
    return function(info,line_number)
        if line_number > max_last_line then
            print(tostring(line_number/total_lines*100)..'%')
            max_last_line = line_number
        end
    end
end

local lines = count_lines()

local thread = coroutine.create( script_function )

debug.sethook(thread, trace(lines), "l")
coroutine.resume(thread)
```

output:

```
20%
hello
40%
world
60%
80%
100%
```

However, it is to mention that it's still quite hard to get meaningful numbers from such a progress report - if you organize your code and the only statement at the end is the call to some kind of main, the progress will be 100%, whereas the number wouldn't represent anything useful. You could also track the lines and measure coverage, but naturally, 100% coverage is not something that you normally have during an execution run. You could also try to build a system for progress reporting and call a function like

```
ReportProgress( tasks / all_tasks )
```

which would be bound to C and would generate the necessary progress update

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for me I run script files which I have no control over, I mean that the user of my application can switch to run any script file (He builds them), in you implementation it depends on the script file itself, I need to be able to handle the percentage through my C application and interface with LUA to get the info required